# Django - How to filter by date with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have some model with a timestamp field:

models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        choices=EVENT_TYPE_CHOICES,
        verbose_name=_("Event Type")
    )
    event_model = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        choices=EVENT_MODEL_CHOICES,
        verbose_name=_("Event Model")
    )
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_("Timestamp"))
```

I'm then using Django-rest-framework to create an API endpoint for this class, with django-filter providing a filtering functionality as follows:

```
from .models import Event
from .serializers import EventSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets, filters
from rest_framework import renderers
from rest_framework_csv import renderers as csv_renderers


class EventsView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    A read only view that returns all audit events in JSON or CSV.
    """
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    renderer_classes = (csv_renderers.CSVRenderer, renderers.JSONRenderer)
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('event_type', 'event_model', 'timestamp')
```

with the following settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',),
}
```

I'm able to filter by `event_type` and `event_model`, but am having trouble filtering by the timestamp field. Essentially, I want to make an API call that equates to the following:

```
AuditEvent.objects.filter(timestamp__gte='2016-01-02 00:00+0000')
```

which I would expect I could do as follows:

```
response = self.client.get("/api/v1/events/?timestamp=2016-01-02 00:00+0000", **{'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'application/json'})
```

though that is incorect. How do I make an API call that returns all objects with a timestamp greater than or equal to a certain value?

Answer (score 17):

To expand on Flaiming's answer, if you're only ever going to be filtering via ISO datetime formats, it helps to overwrite the defaults to always use the `IsoDateTimeFilter`. This can be done per filterset with e.g.

```py
import django_filters
from django.db import models as django_models
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from rest_framework import viewsets

class EventFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = {
            'timestamp': ('lte', 'gte')
        }

    filter_overrides = {
        django_models.DateTimeField: {
            'filter_class': django_filters.IsoDateTimeFilter
        },
    }

class EventsView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    ...
    filter_class = EventFilter
```

You then won't have to worry about setting a different filter for each lookup expression and each field.

Comment: EventFillter cause django backend filter not work anymore

Comment: filters.FilterSet doea not exist anymore in Django 2.1

Comment: Use this instead: from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

Answer (score 9):

You can create specific [`FilterSet`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#specifying-a-filterset) as follows:

```
import django_filters
from rest_framework import filters
from rest_framework import viewsets

class EventFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    timestamp_gte = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name="timestamp", lookup_expr='gte')
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['event_type', 'event_model', 'timestamp', 'timestamp_gte']

class EventsView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    ...
    filter_class = EventFilter
```

Than you can filter by `"/api/v1/events/?timestamp_gte=2016-01-02"`

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, this example uses [django-filter](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still getting 0 responses with that, when I should be getting 1. I've tried using both `django_filters.DateTimeFilter` and `django_filters.IsoDateTimeFilter`. Any idea why that might be the case?

Comment: It works for me but use DateFilter instead of DateTimeFilter. @orange1

Answer (score 8):

`IsoDateTimeFilter` is very picky about the input format; instead of:

- 2016-01-02 00:00+0000

use:

- 2016-01-02T00:00:00Z

Answer (score 2):

A better way is to filter datetime in get_queryset function

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    start_date = self.request.query_params.get('start_date', None)
    end_date = self.request.query_params.get('end_date', None)
    if start_date and end_date:
        queryset = queryset.filter(timstamp__range=[start_date, end_date])
```

Comment: This is not a good example, although it may work for a particular quick and dirty solution, as soon as you have requests of different types this will fail.

Answer (score 2):

## Give parameter in date format instead of timestamp

Since you want to filter by only date not timestamp, you can consider writing customized `django_filters.FilterSet` class.

You can do so by replacing `django_filters.DateTimeFilter` to `django_filters.DateFilter`, adding `__date` as suffix to your timestamp field_name and add `lookup_expr` as `exact` value.

Have a look at code below for example.

##### Model Class

```
class RegistrationLink(models.Model):
    """marketing campaign links"""
    campaign_name = models.CharField("campaign name", max_length=128, unique=True)
    url = models.URLField("URL", max_length=200, null=True, unique=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField("created date and time", auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="user ID", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    visit_count = models.PositiveIntegerField("visit count", null=False, default=0)
```

##### FilterSet Class

```
class RegistrationLinkFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    created_date = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name='created_date__date', lookup_expr="exact")
    campaign_name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = RegistrationLink
        fields = ['campaign_name', 'created_date']
```

##### class based view

```
import django_filters
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter
# ...

class RegistrationLinkViewV2(ListAPIView):
    """Registration links for marketing campaigns"""
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, ManagePermission)

    method = ''
    queryset = RegistrationLink.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LinkSerializer
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter,)
    filterset_class = RegistrationLinkFilter
    filterset_fields = ('campaign_name', 'created_date')
    ordering_fields = ('campaign_name', 'created_date',
                       'url', 'created_by__username')
    ordering = "-created_date"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the case you are looking for. Basically, you can access the params from the views by
`date_params = self.request.query_params.get('params_name')`.

Then you can do
`Event.objects.filter(date__lte=date_params, date__gte=date_params)`

Comment: Maybe you mean: `Event.objects.filter(timestamp__date__gte=date_params_since, timestamp__date__lte=date_params_until)`

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me but this did:

```
class EventFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    start = filters.IsoDateTimeFilter(field_name="start", lookup_expr='gte')
    end = filters.IsoDateTimeFilter(field_name="end", lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = 'start', 'end',
```